# Batch: Run with GPU command?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have a laptop with nVidia and Intel graphics. When I launch a programm, by default it uses Intel graphics, but I can make it use nVidia.
Question: Is there a way to do the same(run it with nVidia gpu) but with a batch script?
Do not suggest other ways, just tell the command.

Comment: in the driver options configure windows to use the nVIDIA card for a specific program

Comment: I know I can change driver options, but I need a batch script.

Comment: use the 3rd party applications RegFrompp or Regshot, monitor which settings are changed and run this change via reg.exe in a cmd.

Comment: @JohnGmdv Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm also looking to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

From cmd.exe I use

```
set SHIM_MCCOMPAT=0x800000001
Downloads\wglgears.exe -info
```

to observe the beloved gears in rotation with "high performance". It turns out that vsync is obtained, unlike with the integrated gpu (`0x800000000`), so the gears rotate smoothly. In practice I can thus spot the difference easily, without the `-info` switch.

To check the variable value you need, use the right-click gui method on cmd.exe and echo the variable.

Anyone familiar with PS here to convert the above commands?

Answer (score 0):

A key within the Windows registry controls which GPU is used per app. Below reg file will force Brave browser to use iGPU (GpuPreference=1 on my system). I named the file `BraveGpuOff.reg`. Command is `regedit BraveGpuOff.reg`. I'm assuming it generalizes to other apps. I used nirsoft's `RegistryChangesView` app to discover which key(s) gets changed when Settings->Graphics Settings options change. To use dedicated GPU change to `GpuPreference=0`.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\DirectX\UserGpuPreferences]
"C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe"="AutoHDREnable=1;GpuPreference=1;"
```